# print toString() doesn't print ArrayList Class member objects

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

Why does `print toString()` doesn't print Array Class member objects? It says "cannot return a void result". What type of result does it want when my ArrayList private objects contain values.

Eg: In `Person` class-

```
public class Person { 

    private ArrayList <String> name;

    private ArrayList <Integer> number;

    public Person(ArrayList <String> thatName, ArrayList <Integer> thatNumber) 
    {
        name = new ArrayList <String>(thatName);
        number = new ArrayList <Integer>(thatNumber);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getNumber() 
    {
        return number;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return System.out.println(name + "" + number); //Gives error "cannot return a void result"    
    }
```

Also, can I make `String.format(,)` work in this case? I tried, but it doesn't work as the ArrayList object types are not primitive data types.

EDIT:

Here is how I am calling `Person` class but `toString()` not printing anything.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PersonTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList <String> nam = new ArrayList <String>();
    ArrayList <Integer> numb = new ArrayList <Integer>();

    nam.add("Zeus");
    numb.add(99);

    Person pr = new Person(nam, numb);

    pr.toString();

}

}
```

Comment: Read the documentation. Learn the Java API. Understand the very self-explanatory error message... *Question does not show research effort* is on the hover text of the down arrow.

Comment: Well, first, this won't even compile ... so the title **print toString() doesn't print ArrayList Class member objects** is not correct.

Comment: @AxelH, how would it have worked?

Comment: You are probably running the last compilable code ... Error are not only there to warn you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.out.println is a void, therefore can't return anything.
What you should do is :

```
public String toString()
{
  return name + " " + number;
}
```

and in  the caller, use person instance to print :

```
System.out.println(person.toString());
```

or below, since printing an object will automatically invoke the toString() method.

```
System.out.println(person);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. I posted my calling method and its class. Please help

Comment: after you make changes in the toString() method, for the calling class just put System.out.println(pr.toString())

Comment: @Zeus You may also simply `System.out.println(person)`

Comment: ah yes thats true

Answer (score 2):

You want to return a string, `println` is a `void` method.

Change

```
return System.out.println(name + "" + number)
```

to `return name + "" + number;`

> Also, can I make String.format(,) work in this case?

Sure. `return String.format("Names: %s\nNumbers: %s", name, number);`

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. I posted my calling method and its class. Please help.

Comment: @Zeus, `pr.toString()` won't do anything expect getting a String value. You need to print the value via `System.out.print(String)`. And this can't be done in the `toString()` (not on the return line at least) method because this need to return a String. Read the full answer !